# sql view for items not sold in last 6 months

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a view where I would like to get a list of Items that are not sold in last 6 months. I tried couple of approaches but none is working correct.
Please guide me.
I have one table for sales data mart that has the item no and I'm getting item no from another table which is an Item table for a list of all items.
here are 2 approaches:
I cannot make temp tables as this is a view?

```
select distinct a.ItemID, a.TranDate Into #Itemslast6months 
from SalesDataMart a
where TranDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)

Select distinct m.ITMNO_0 into #ItemsNotSoldLast6Months
from ITEMMASTER  as m
Where not exists (select ItemID
                    from #Itemslast6months as B
                    where m.ITMNO_0 = B.ItemID)


Select n.ITMNO_0, s.[Description], max(s.TranDate) last_Transaction_Date
from #temsNotSoldLast6Months n
join SalesDataMart s on n.ITMNO_0 = s.ItemID
group by n.ITMNO_0, s.[Description]
```

2nd Approach:

---

```
 WITH ItemsSoldLast6Months (ItemID, TranDate)
      AS
      (
        select distinct a.ItemID, a.TranDate 
        from SalesDataMart a
        where TranDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)

      )

  WITH ItemsNotSoldLast6Months (ItemNO)
      AS
      (
      Select distinct m.ITMNO_0 
from ITEMMASTER  as m
Where not exists (select ItemID
                    from ItemsSoldLast6Months as B
                    where m.ITMNO_0 = B.ItemID)

    )


Select n.ITMNO_0, s.[Description], max(s.TranDate) last_Transaction_Date
from #temsNotSoldLast6Months n
join SalesDataMart s on n.ITMNO_0 = s.ItemID
group by n.ITMNO_0, s.[Description]
```

Comment: Thanks, since I need it for a report that will run monthly, If I create a real table, then do I need add a drop table statement before running the statement?

Answer (score 0):

This *seems* to be what you are looking for but it's hard to tell without a sample dataset or the DDL from your tables.

```
Select distinct 
    m.ITMNO_0, 
    s.[Description], 
    max(s.TranDate) last_Transaction_Date
from ITEMMASTER  as m
join SalesDataMart s on m.ITMNO_0 = s.ItemID
Where not exists (  select distinct a.ItemID 
                    from SalesDataMart a
                    where a.TranDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0))
group by m.ITMNO_0, s.[Description]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table of items is ItemMaster and your sales transactions are in SalesDataMart, your query would look like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM    ITEMMASTER AS m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ItemID
                     FROM   SalesDataMart AS S
                     WHERE  m.ITMNO_0 = S.ItemID
                            AND TranDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
                   );
```

If an item was sold in the last 6 months, it would be filtered out of the query on ItemMaster